Compose Conditional Modifier Not Working Properly
I tried making an extension function on Modifier to apply changes to it only if a condition was true, since quite frequently I need to make small changes to a Modifier object in case certain things happen. But the code is not working as expected and I can't seem to understand why.
This is the extension function
inline fun Modifier.conditional(
    condition: Boolean,
    ifTrue: Modifier.() -> Modifier
): Modifier = if (condition) {
    ifTrue(this)
} else {
    this
}

And this is how I am using it:
@Composable
fun PlusMinusButton(
    text: String,
    enabled: Boolean,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(60.dp)
            .background(
                color = if (enabled) Blue02 else Gray1,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
            )
            .conditional(enabled) {
                clickable { onClick() }
            },
        text = text,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        fontSize = 32.sp,
        color = if (enabled) Blue06 else Blue02
    )
}

And this is how it's looking on the preview:

Whenever the conditional is true, it seems the rest of the modifier is ignored, and the background doesn't get applied. Any ideas what can be causing this?

I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe, the code you provided works perfectly fine for me.

@Leviathan that is weird... Here it sometimes work and sometimes doesn't. Something is quite nor right...

I can't reproduce it either. You might want to check that you properly toggle the enabled variable and that you have recent dependency versions in your build.gradle.

This seems to be working fine, although it does depend on how you call your composable.
This is an example of how it can be used:
                var counter by remember {
                    mutableIntStateOf(0)
                }
                Row(
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    PlusMinusButton(text = "-", enabled = counter > 0) {
                        counter--
                    }
                    Text(text = counter.toString())
                    PlusMinusButton(text = "+", enabled = true) {
                        counter++
                    }
                }

You could also take into consideration using "then", which returns a concatenation of the initial modifier with the given one.
Usage:
fun Modifier.conditional(
condition: Boolean,
extraModifier: Modifier): Modifier = this.then(
if (condition) {
    extraModifier
} else Modifier)

And the usage for this would be:
.conditional(enabled, Modifier.clickable { onClick() }),


Thanks for your reply. This is a thing that I do not quite understand. What does then do differently than just applying the same "functions" to the current modifier using "this" and then returning it?

They should both work equally well. I wanted to suggest the then modifier instead of ifTrue(this) because it might be easier to understand by other devs reading your code.
Were you able to call this method and have the expected behaviour?
